# Images overlap when zoomed

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put 4 images in a line in HTML and with a CSS code to zoom them when mouse over it
HTML Code:

```
<img class="Images" src="Images/image1.jpg" style="position:absolute; top:590px; left: 420px;">
<img class="Images" src="Images/image2.jpg" style="position:absolute; top:590px; left: 590px;">
<img class="Images" src="Images/image3.jpg" style="position:absolute; top:590px; left: 760px;">
<img class="Images" src="Images/image4.jpg" style="position:absolute; top:590px; left: 930px;">
```

CSS Code:

```
.Images{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.Images:hover{
    -moz-transform:scale(4);
    -o-transform:scale(4);
    -webkit-transform:scale(4);
}
```

My problem is, when I zoom the first image, it shows the next of them inside of the image, when I zoom the second image, it shows the next of them inside of the image but the first image is hidden under the second image and so on. How am I suppose to hide the next images too.

Comment: What do you want? your question makes no sense?

Comment: How to stop the images to overlap

Comment: "How am I suppose to hide the next images too." It depends on what you want. Do you want to hide any image that is not being zoomed in? Here is a JSFiddle btw https://jsfiddle.net/9w1go1hr/

Comment: Please include the standard `transform:scale(4)` as well, because the properties with vendor prefixes are going to be removed in the future.

Answer (score 3):

So it sounds like you want the image being hovered to be in front of the others. To do this you use the z-index CSS property to specify the stack order : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

```
.Images{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    z-index:0;
}
.Images:hover{
    -moz-transform:scale(4);
    -o-transform:scale(4);
    -webkit-transform:scale(4);
    z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use z-index on hover

```css
.Images{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.Images:hover{
    -moz-transform:scale(4);
    -o-transform:scale(4);
    -webkit-transform:scale(4);
    z-index:100;
}
```

```html
<img class="Images" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" style="position:absolute; top:590px; left: 420px;">
<img class="Images" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" style="position:absolute; top:590px; left: 590px;">
<img class="Images" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" style="position:absolute; top:590px; left: 760px;">
<img class="Images" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" style="position:absolute; top:590px; left: 930px;">
```